# Update in SQL not working

Tags: php, sql

First of all, let me tell you that I am a beginner in PHP & SQL. So, bear with me.
I have a table with only one row and one column that is Date_Latest.
I have to edit this field. The following is my code in PHP:-

```
$result = "UPDATE Admin SET Date_Latest='$dt'";
if(mysql_query($result){
echo "SUCCESS";
}
else
{echo "OOPS! SOMETHING WENT WRONG";}
}
```

The code is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `not working` means do you get any error? Have you connected to database?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? What database are you using? Also you probably need a WHERE-clause in your query

Comment: No error is being shown. It is probably a syntax error and $dt is not null. I want to replace all the values of Date_Latest

Comment: Check your error/s by `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: @M1K1O, stil there is no output

Comment: If your table only has one column, you are changing the primary key and that is a bad idea. You might get it to work now, but it will fail again when there are more rows as the primary key has to be unique. Apart from that, changing the primary key is never a good idea as you might want to reference specific rows in the future.

Comment: Try running the query from phpmyadmin and see what error it returns.

Comment: there is no primary key in the table @jeroen

Comment: That is kind of inevitable if you only have one column.

Comment: @Starx, it was a success using phpmyadmin...I used a random string instead of the variable

Comment: Brian got the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't there a problem with the brackets?

```
if(mysql_query($result)){
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
else {
    echo "OOPS! SOMETHING WENT WRONG";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$result = "UPDATE Admin SET Date_Latest='".$dt."'";
```

And make sure that `$dt` is non empty and your DB is connected.And try to avoid using `mysql_*` functions due to they are deprecated.Instead use `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO` statements.

And your query will update all the records.If you want to update an particular then use `WHERE` clause with it.

Main thing.Check whether you are sending the data of same type that you have given in table column

Comment: @Gautam3164, the code is not working still...thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Are you having `Date_Latest` column with same name..??

Comment: This really does not make a difference.

Comment: I have a table named Admn with ONLY A SINGLE column Date_Latest and ONLY A SINGLE row, i.e. the value

Comment: And are you sending same datatype values also..??

Comment: Brian got the answer Gautam

Answer (score 0):

If this code is not working then you can try :

```
mysql_query($result) or die(mysql_error());
```

If your code is wrong then it will show the error in your syntax

Answer (score 0):

You tried changing all rows in table, because you're missing parameter `WHERE`. So you need to add one more column in your table, e.g. id

If you want to change just first row, add `LIMIT` parameter

```
UPDATE `Admin` SET `Date_Latest` = '{$dt}' WHERE id = '{$some}'

UPDATE `Admin` SET `Date_Latest` = '{$dt}' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  the following statement  to execute statement

```
 mysql_execute($statement);
```